# Lag in animations using animate function

Tags: android, animation

I am making an app in which I used some animations. I used animate function for very basic animation. But there is very much noticeably lag in the animation.

```
public void drop(View view){

    ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;
    counter.setTranslationY(-500);
    counter.animate().translationYBy(500).rotation(3600).setDuration(300);
}
```

And there is some other code of my app.
I don't know the reason behind lagging. Please someone help me in it.

Answer (score 0):

Translation isn't a very heavy operation, but rotation can be.  But, if you have other operations going on at the same time they can cause other problems.  You can get a better idea of where time is being spent by using traceview (your app only) and systrace (your app and interactions with other parts of the system.)